# Swift core data code that only works sometimes

Tags: swift

I wrote this code to set the value to 1 on a property of an xcdatamodeld entity called `Variables` in `viewDidLoad`. The problem is that when the code runs, half the time `res.valueForKey("runningForFirstTime")`, equals nil and half the time `res.valueForKey("runningForFirstTime")` equals 1. Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```
var appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Variables")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
var newVar: AnyObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Variables", inManagedObjectContext: context)

var results:Array = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
var res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
println(res.valueForKey("runningForFirstTime"))
if res.valueForKey("runningForFirstTime") == nil{
     //some code
     println("This is nil")
}
newVar.setValue(1, forKey: "runningForFirstTime")
println(res.valueForKey("runningForFirstTime"))
```

Comment: I tried to understand your question... but i'm not.... can you point to detail of your problem?

Comment: the point is the newVar.setValue(1, forKey: "runningForFirstTime") only works about half the time

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Variables")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

Ok so we have a fetch request to find all `Variables` entities.

```
var newVar: AnyObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Variables", inManagedObjectContext: context)
```

Then we insert a new instance of the `Variables` entity. Now there are one or more `Variables` in our context.

```
var results:Array = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!
```

Now we execute that fetch request to retrieve all of those `Variables` instances...

```
var res = results[0] as! NSManagedObject
```

...and grab whichever `Variables` happens to be the first result.

Every time you run this code block you insert yet another `Variables` entity into your context. You might then fetch an instance you had used previously which has had its `runningForFirstTime` property set or you might get the object you just created which has not.

Comment: To add onto Jonah's final point, an NSFetchRequest does not implement any sorting by default. Therefore, since one of the Variables in the context's fetched results does not have it's property set, your line of code: res = results[0] could randomly return that fetched NSManagedObject with the unset property.

Comment: @tom333777 that depends on what you intended this code to do and that's not obvious to me from your question. Consider how many `Variables` entities you want to have, when you want to be creating them, and how you want to handle the case when none yet exist. If you only expect to have a single `Variables` then you should check if one exists before creating a new one.